# How to compare coefficients between mlogit models in R?

Tags: r, mlogit

I would like to know what the appropriate statistical method is, to compare B Coefficients between multinomial logit models in R.

My dataset consist of stated preferences data that I obtained from a choice based conjoint experiment and has the so-called long shape. For my experiment there were two experimental conditions, the 'brand' condition and the 'retail' condition. The same independent variables were used (dealer, fuel, brand, price and maintain with the same levels).

What I actually want to examine, is whether there are differences between the coefficients of the multinomial logit models. Below the output of the two models (brand12 and retailer12) are summarized. Thus, in the `ml.brand12` model, the estimate for price is `-1.1159e` and in the `ml.retailer12` model `-1.4122e-04`? How can I examine in a statistical correct way whether this difference is significant?

```
> summary(ml.brand12)
Call:
mlogit(formula = choice ~ dealer + fuel + brand + price + maintain | 
    -1, data = brand12, method = "nr", print.level = 0)

Frequencies of alternatives:
     a1      a2      a3      a4 
0.28487 0.28558 0.32383 0.10573 

nr method
5 iterations, 0h:0m:1s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 3.33E-05 
successive function values within tolerance limits 

Coefficients :
            Estimate  Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
dealer    5.1015e-01  2.9764e-02  17.140 < 2.2e-16 ***
fuel      7.0856e-01  2.5510e-02  27.776 < 2.2e-16 ***
brand     5.1019e-01  2.7346e-02  18.657 < 2.2e-16 ***
price    -1.1159e-04  7.5306e-06 -14.818 < 2.2e-16 ***
maintain -2.8398e-03  1.2257e-04 -23.169 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log-Likelihood: -4508.5

> summary(ml.retailer12)
Call:
mlogit(formula = choice ~ dealer + fuel + brand + price + maintain | 
    -1, data = retailer12, method = "nr", print.level = 0)

Frequencies of alternatives:
     a1      a2      a3      a4 
0.27949 0.29038 0.30957 0.12056 

nr method
5 iterations, 0h:0m:1s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 0.000383 
successive function values within tolerance limits 

Coefficients :
            Estimate  Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
dealer    6.3709e-01  3.0155e-02  21.127 < 2.2e-16 ***
fuel      7.0651e-01  2.5560e-02  27.642 < 2.2e-16 ***
brand     4.8755e-01  2.8071e-02  17.369 < 2.2e-16 ***
price    -1.4122e-04  7.7595e-06 -18.200 < 2.2e-16 ***
maintain -2.9467e-03  1.2550e-04 -23.479 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```